# What's power density in a mosfet

Tags: power, mosfet

Can anyone help me understand what is power density, as I read this term very often in papers, seems so intuitive, but couldn't know what it means in a deeper sense. Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Please link the document in which you read the term (as applied to MOSFETs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could mean two things:

1. This could be referring to thermal power density meaning how fast power is generated and removed from the part. Another term would be electrical power density, but usually current density this would occur in research or mosfet design literature
2. General power density in electronics, usually meaning you can fit more parts or have a smaller footprint because the package and die are more efficient dealing with heat and thermal.

Comment: in terms of the electric field in the mosfet, usually the channel area, The power generated in that area, can it also fit the definition of power density in power mosfet? in this context, how can we explain the power density better?